# What is the best way to do Rails 4 link_to :delete if JS may be disabled?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, tor, ujs

Here's a very standard bit of code (Rails 4):

`<%= link_to 'Log out', logout_path, :method => :delete %>`

However, here's a nonstandard consideration: no Javascript. Without Javascript, jquery_ujs doesn't get its hooks in, so the link creates a plain `GET /logout`, which has no route.

Why? Because I want to support a Tor hidden site version of the site, and I have to assume that Tor users (coming most likely via the Tor Browser Bundle) will have JavaScript disabled. (I deliberately do not want to enable JS for them, to prevent various potential privacy leaks. I also don't want to permit XSRF attacks that would e.g. allow someone to log out my users with a GET, nor make the UI ugly with a button.)

The hidden site is lower functionality than the main site (e.g. no payments accepted via tor), but some basic things like login/logout really ought to work correctly.

What's the best way to support this?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can create a `form` using a form helper. This would allow you to specify the `method` to use. What Rails will do is generate a hidden field inside that `form` that specifies the HTTP method, which on submitting is then used by Rails to determine which controller action to call.

The only thing left to do then is to write some CSS to make the submit button look like a link, but you can easily find that on the webs.